# SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise named instance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation, instance

I have sql server 2008 r2 installed and I am using 3 named instances (2 express and 1 developer). For a task I need to use the CDC (change data capture) which is only in the enterprise edition. I have downloaded the trial from [Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=1279).

Given that I'm wondering if this should be done same as installing a new named instance or is it an upgrade?

Comment: Depends if you want to make a 4th instance or upgrade one of your current installations. As it's a trial, I'd lean towards a separate instance so once 180 days are up you're not left with the task of downgrading.

Comment: Why do you have three instances in the first place? Also, CDC will also work in Developer Edition...

Comment: @Aaron There are multiple instances since ex employees have installed their own instance each time and there is no documentation on them! Its a bit of a mess and I'd rather not play with their data.

Comment: @JohnM thanks for tip, I wasn't thinking about downgrading. A separate instance seems to be the better option!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support Multiple instances on single windows machine so it is fully supported when you want to install another version of SQL Server same machine having other versions. But have you made sure that windows server/machine would perfectly support all four instances. Is the hardware resource optimum for your testing won't you face hardware crunch if all 4 instances are required and they are up and running.

Plus why are you still stuck up with SQL Server 2008 R2 edition. The link you posted in your question is pointing to SQL Server 2008 so are you installing SQL server 2008 or 2008 R2. Both does not falls under category of normal support but yes falls under category of extended support, and that too not for very long and soon will become totally unsupported. I would advise you to do your testing at least on [SQL Server 2012 Evaluation edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29066) or SQL Server 2014

> Given that I'm wondering if this should be done same as installing a new named instance or is it an upgrade?

You can do a normal installation but before moving please read carefully [hardware and software requirement for installing SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If you are installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on windows 8 you must read [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562/en-gb) before proceeding